Add custom block to submenu variation
I've created a custom block, and with it, a block variation of the core sub-menu block that allows the custom block to be added to it. I can get the custom block to show up initially in the sub-menu variation, as I can add it to the innerBlocks template. However, that doesn't include it in the 'add block' dialog for the sub-menu variation or allow for it to be dragged in. My instinct is to add the custom block to an 'allowedBlocks' attribute, but I can't find any reference to that in the block variations documentation.
Here's the sub-menu variation code:
registerBlockVariation(
    'core/navigation-submenu',
    {
        name: 'cc-sub-menu',
        title: 'Enhanced Sub-menu',
        description: 'Allows for additional block types',
        icon: 'welcome-widgets-menus',
        attributes: { providerNameSlug: 'cc-submenu' },
        scope: [ 'block', 'inserter', 'transform' ],
        innerBlocks: [
            ['cc/custom-block'],
            ['core/paragraph']
        ],
        isActive: ( blockAttributes, variationAttributes ) =>
            blockAttributes.providerNameSlug === variationAttributes.providerNameSlug
    }
);

I've even dumbed down the above code by removing the custom block and just trying to add a core/paragraph block to the innerBlocks attribute of the submenu variation, and the same problem exists. Is there an allowedBlocks setting on innerBlocks that I can manipulate in this way, or does that functionality not exist at the moment?
